# Выпадающий список с данными из бд

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Создаю CRUD приложение. Есть две таблицы `type` и `category`:

```
CREATE TABLE `type` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sort` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `categoryId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `category_idx` (`categoryId`),
  CONSTRAINT `categoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryId`) REFERENCES 
 `category_production` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
  ) 

CREATE TABLE `category_production` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
   UNIQUE KEY `category_UNIQUE` (`category`)
)
```

Удаление, изменение и создание данных работает правильно. Проблема появилась когда хотел создать выпадающий список `category` для `type`, т.е. при создании записи в `type` должен быть список с данными из предыдущей таблицы. 
Сама форма выпадающего списка создалась, но данных в ней нет. 
Как это можно справить?

[image: type table]

`Type.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "type")
public class Type implements Serializable{
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "sort")
private String sort;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "categoryId")
private Category category;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSort() {
    return sort;
}

public void setSort(String sort) {
    this.sort = sort;
}

public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Type{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", sort='" + sort + '\'' +
            ", category=" + category +
            '}';
  }
}
```

`Category.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category_production")
public class Category {
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "category", unique = true)
private String name_category;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName_category() {
    return name_category;
}

public void setName_category(String name_category) {
    this.name_category = name_category;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Category{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name_category='" + name_category + '\'' +
            '}';
  }
}
```

`TypeController.java`

```
@Controller
public class TypeController {

private TypeService typeService;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "typeService")
public void setTypeService(TypeService typeService) {
    this.typeService = typeService;
}

private CategoryService categoryService;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "categoryService")
public void setCategoryService(CategoryService categoryService) {
    this.categoryService = categoryService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "types", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listType(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("type", new Type());
    model.addAttribute("listType", this.typeService.listType());

    return "types";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/types/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addType(@ModelAttribute("type") Type type,@ModelAttribute("category") Category category){
    if (type.getId()==0){
        this.typeService.addType(type);
        this.categoryService.addCategory(category);
    }else {
        this.typeService.updateType(type);
        this.categoryService.updateCategory(category);
    }

    return "redirect:/types";
}

@RequestMapping("/removetype/{id}")
public String removeType(@PathVariable("id") int id){
    this.typeService.removeType(id);
    this.categoryService.removeCategory(id);

    return "redirect:/types";
}

@RequestMapping("/edittype/{id}")
public String editType(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("type", this.typeService.getTypeById(id));
    model.addAttribute("listType", this.typeService.listType());
    model.addAttribute("category", this.categoryService.getCategoryById(id));
    model.addAttribute("listCategory", this.categoryService.listCategory());

    return "types";
}


@RequestMapping("typedata/{id}")
public String typeData(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("type", this.typeService.getTypeById(id));

    return "typedata";

  }
}
```

Часть html кода, где создаю выпадающий список(`types.jsp`):

```
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="category.id">Category:</form:label></td>
                    <td>
                        <form:select path="category.id" cssStyle="width: 150px;">
                            <form:option value="2">Select a category</form:option>
                            <c:forEach items="${listCategory}" var="category">
                                <form:option value="${category.id}">${category.name_category}</form:option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </form:select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

  /.../

      <c:if test="${!empty listType}">
<table class="tg">
    <tr>
        <th width="60">ID</th>
        <th width="150">Sort</th>
        <th width="150">Category</th>
        <th width="50">Edit</th>
        <th width="50">Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${listType}" var="type">
        <tr>
            <td>${type.id}</td>
            <td><a href="/typedata/${type.id}" target="_blank">${type.sort}</a></td>
            <td>${category.name_category}</td>
            <td><a href="<c:url value="/edittype/${type.id}"/>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="<c:url value="/removetype/${type.id}"/>">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: И при открытии `/edittype/{id}` тоже?

Comment: Добавил данные в самом mysql. Когда зашел в приложение в столбце `category` было пусто, открыв `/edittype/{id}` появилась запись и нажав кнопку `edit type`(для сохранения изменений) выдало ошибку:  nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Comment: Ошибка указывает на то что неправильный SQL.